# Lararel Vite - npm run dev didn't work on CentOS

Tags: laravel, apache, centos, vite

I want to test [Remote Development using SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) via Visual Studio Code but I faced an issue.

On my VM (CentOS 8) I set up earlier working `Apache` with few applications. Therefore they was working with `Laravel Mix`.

Now, when `Vite` comes out, I was trying to "host" the projects but `npm run dev` didn't work.

```
Node version: v10.23.1

npm version: 6.14.10
```

The error while I try to run `npm run dev` or `npm run build`:

```
[user@server ssh-test-app]$ npm run dev

> @ dev /var/www/ssh-test-app
> vite

/var/www/apps/ssh-test-app/node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js:2
import { performance } from 'node:perf_hooks'
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `vite`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2022-09-08T08_17_44_296Z-debug.log
```

Any idea where to find help? Also did `npm install`:

```
[user@server ssh-test-app]$ npm install
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!

> esbuild@0.14.51 postinstall /var/www/apps/ssh-test-app/node_modules/esbuild
> node install.js

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-android-64@0.14.51 (node_modules/esbuild-android-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-android-64@0.14.51: wanted {"os":"android","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-android-arm64@0.14.51 (node_modules/esbuild-android-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-android-arm64@0.14.51: wanted {"os":"android","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-darwin-64@0.14.51 (node_modules/esbuild-darwin-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-darwin-64@0.14.51: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-darwin-arm64@0.14.51 (node_modules/esbuild-darwin-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-darwin-arm64@0.14.51: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-freebsd-64@0.14.51 (node_modules/esbuild-freebsd-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-freebsd-64@0.14.51: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-freebsd-arm64@0.14.51 (node_modules/esbuild-freebsd-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-freebsd-arm64@0.14.51: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-32@0.14.51 (node_modules/esbuild-linux-32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-32@0.14.51: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-arm@0.14.51 (node_modules/esbuild-linux-arm):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-arm@0.14.51: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-arm64@0.14.51 (node_modules/esbuild-linux-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-arm64@0.14.51: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-mips64le@0.14.51 (node_modules/esbuild-linux-mips64le):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-mips64le@0.14.51: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"mips64el"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-ppc64le@0.14.51 (node_modules/esbuild-linux-ppc64le):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-ppc64le@0.14.51: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"ppc64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-riscv64@0.14.51 (node_modules/esbuild-linux-riscv64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-riscv64@0.14.51: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"riscv64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-linux-s390x@0.14.51 (node_modules/esbuild-linux-s390x):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-linux-s390x@0.14.51: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"s390x"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-netbsd-64@0.14.51 (node_modules/esbuild-netbsd-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-netbsd-64@0.14.51: wanted {"os":"netbsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-openbsd-64@0.14.51 (node_modules/esbuild-openbsd-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-openbsd-64@0.14.51: wanted {"os":"openbsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-sunos-64@0.14.51 (node_modules/esbuild-sunos-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-sunos-64@0.14.51: wanted {"os":"sunos","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-windows-32@0.14.51 (node_modules/esbuild-windows-32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-windows-32@0.14.51: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-windows-64@0.14.51 (node_modules/esbuild-windows-64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-windows-64@0.14.51: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: esbuild-windows-arm64@0.14.51 (node_modules/esbuild-windows-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for esbuild-windows-arm64@0.14.51: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

added 1 package, updated 91 packages and audited 112 packages in 8.775s

18 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I want to remind that the project was copied in some "developing phase" to the test VM from Windows.

The other apps on VM with former `Laravel Mix` are working.

Comment: Vite requires Node 16 as far as I know

Comment: I've updated it... I must manually do it, because from repo it takes the `10.*` version of node... Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue, and it is the outdated version of Node for sure.

Unfortunately, the version from the repo is too old, so I fixed it by removing (and purging the configuration) and reinstalling the latest versions of both Node and npm from another source.

I followed [this answer on the askubuntu website](https://askubuntu.com/a/1170408/264386) to remove Node and Npm and purge the configuration:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* ~/.npm
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node*
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/include/node*

sudo apt-get purge nodejs npm
sudo apt autoremove
```

Then, I reinstalled Node easily, adding the repository as described in the [NodeSource Github repository](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#installation-instructions) - *note: have a look at the Node repository for updates on the installation steps*

```
## UBUNTU, DEBIAN
# 1. Download and import the Nodesource GPG key
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg
sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource-repo.gpg.key | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg

# 2. Create deb repository
NODE_MAJOR=20
echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/nodesource.gpg] https://deb.nodesource.com/node_$NODE_MAJOR.x nodistro main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list

# 3. Run Update and Install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs -y

## FEDORA, REDHAT, AMAZON LINUX
sudo yum install https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_20.x/nodistro/repo/nodesource-release-nodistro-1.noarch.rpm -y
sudo yum install nodejs -y --setopt=nodesource-nodejs.module_hotfixes=1f
```

At last, I reinstalled [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm)

```
curl -qL https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```